# Swagger Invalid json message received

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, swagger

I'm using Symfony 4 with Doctrine and now I'm implementing / adding Swagger, so I will have proper docs where testing my api will be available.

This is my postman, with proper inputed form data and OK response.
[image]

And this are my "problematic" notations of Swagger

```
 * @Route(
 *     "/request",
 *     name="create",
 *     methods={"POST"}
 * )
 *
 * @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="domain",
 *     in="formData",
 *     required=true,
 *     type="array",
 *          @SWG\Items(
 *             type="string"
 *          )
 * ),
 *
 * @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="name",
 *     in="formData",
 *     required=true,
 *     type="string",
 * ),
 *
 * @SWG\Response(
 *     response=200,
 *     description="OK",
 *     @SWG\Schema(
 *          type="array",
 *          @Model(type=App\Entity\Request::class)
 *     )
 * ),
 *
 * @SWG\Response(
 *     response=201,
 *     description="Request created",
 *     @SWG\Schema(
 *          type="array",
 *          @Model(type=App\Entity\Request::class)
 *     )
 * ),
```

So now I open a Swagger via myurl.com/api/doc and try to execute the same...
[image]

So my swagger executes following curl request

```
curl -X POST "http://certify.test/request" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "domain=antrax.com,www.antrax.com&name=antrax.com%2Cwww.antrax.com"
```

And the response is

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "code": 0,
  "message": "Invalid json message received"
}
```

Can you guys, please help me out properly annotate my swagger params so my API doc will be able to make proper request. If you need any additional information's please let me know and I will provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the **Content-type** send by Swagger is not correct.

Using Postman you are sending a **Content-type** header equal to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but with Swagger it is equal to `application/json`.

Try adding the [consumes](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/mime-types/) key in your Swagger annotations like:

```
 * @SWG\Post(
 *     path="/request",
 *     consumes={"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
 * )
```

Also you should change the `domain` param to `domain[]`:

```
@SWG\Parameter(
*     name="domain[]",
*     in="formData",
*     description="Array of domains for TSL certificate",
*     required=true,
*     type="array",
*          @SWG\Items(
*             type="string"
*          )
* )
```

Comment: yeaa its better now, but I get another error... So my curl right now looks like this
`curl -X POST "http://certify.test/request" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "domain=test.com&name=test.com"`

but it should be like this

`curl -X POST "http://certify.test/request" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "domain[]=test.com&name=test.com"`

So the domain must be an array. Do you know what is the problem?